# issue while intercepting and replacing syscall in C

Tags: c, system-calls, method-swizzling

I'm trying to intercept all "syscall"s for my code. I'm able to receive the calls, but for some reason my implementation of syscall is not equivalent, because at some point the program crashes if I activate the replacement, while it works without the replacement.

The reason why I'm doing this is to understand better which calls in my program (and its dependencies) use which syscall's. I know I could use things like ptrace, etc. but now for me it's really more about understanding why this does not work. This is running on arm64 linux.

Here my syscall replacement implementation:

```
long syscall(long number, ...){
    printf("Intercepted syscall: %lu\n", number);
    va_list original_args;
    va_start(original_args, number);

    long (*original_syscall)(long number, ...) = NULL;
    original_syscall = (long (*)(long, ...))dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "syscall");
    long result = original_syscall(number, original_args);
    va_end(original_args);
    return result;
}
```

Here the logs:

```
Intercepted syscall: 178
Intercepted syscall: 178
Intercepted syscall: 178
Intercepted syscall: 178
Intercepted syscall: 178
Intercepted syscall: 57
Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 3606 (Thread-2)
```

Comment: The problem here is that you can't implicitly pass a `va_list` into varargs (ellipsis `...`). What happens is that the varargs function will get a single parameter of type `va_list`, instead of the correct parameters. You'll have to dispatch the syscall number and find the correct number (and types) of arguments.

Comment: You do know that printf calls `write`.

Comment: @stark I was not aware but this it makes sense. Thx for pointing it out.

Comment: @DarkAtom is there a way I can do this programmatically on the fly? I.e. leveraging assembly?

Comment: Yes, it is possible via assembly. In fact it is trivial. First call your printf (and whatever other business you may want to do) and then, after clearing up your own stack, perform a **jump** to the original syscall function. Assuming you left the return address and arguments unchanged (make sure to preserve the register arguments), it will behave as if your caller called the original syscall. I can add an answer, but I am afraid I don't master arm64 that well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not very easy to do in C. You would have to manually parse the argument list (because there is no standard way to redirect a `va_list` to a variadic function).

It is probably easier to use assembly (not tested):

```
message:
    .asciz "Intercepted syscall: %lu\n"
func:
    .asciz "syscall"

syscall:
    stp x29, x30, [sp, -80]!
    stp x0, x1, [sp, 16]
    stp x2, x3, [sp, 32]
    stp x4, x5, [sp, 48]
    stp x6, x7, [sp, 64]
    mov x1, x0
    adr x0, message
    bl printf
    adr x1, func
    mov x0, -1
    bl dlsym
    mov x8, x0
    ldp x6, x7, [sp, 64]
    ldp x4, x5, [sp, 48]
    ldp x2, x3, [sp, 32]
    ldp x0, x1, [sp, 16]
    ldp x29, x30, [sp], 80
    br x0
```

The idea being that you leave the argument list intact (preserving all possible register arguments `x0`-`x7`) and simply jump to the original system call function (via `br`). Since the return address is already in `x30`, the function will return to our caller and not to us. This is an optimization that compilers [already apply](https://godbolt.org/z/sndbh55Wv) to wrappers, but unfortunately there's no way to forward the varargs list to another variadic function in C.

As @stark mentioned, the `printf` may perform a `write`, which can lead to infinite recursion (especially because `stdout` is line-buffered and the `\n` flushes it). The only real "safe" place where you can attempt to log your data is memory (and try to write it later), but that brings a whole lot of headaches by itself so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I'm able to redirect the calls to this implementation and I'm learning a lot (thank you!!!). Now the error I'm getting is `SIGBUS (signal SIGBUS: illegal alignment)`

If I add `.align 2` before `syscall:` the debugger is capable of getting all the way to `br x0`. If I don't add `.align 2` it crashes with the same alignment error on the first line `stp x29, x30, [sp, -80]!`.

To test I renamed the function to `abcde` and am calling it manually in C after having it declared this way: `extern "C" long abcde(long number, ...);`

Comment: What you want to do (most likely) is place the strings in `.rodata` and place the function in `.text` (which I didn't include for simplicity, but should definitely be done). I don't know how the assembler aligns stuff by default, but I suspect that if you start the `.text` section with code only (no strings), it will be correctly aligned.